# When a pastor gets a marriage license from the state are they required to marry homosexuals?

Tags: marriage

I've heard a lot of controversy over whether or not pastors who deny same sex couples should be fined, jailed, etc. If the pastor is licensed by the state don't they then **have to** be religiously unbiased like any government employee or establishment?

Comment: In the United States, marriage licenses are granted to the couple to be married, not to any ceremonial officiant.  I'm not aware of religious officiants who are licensed by states.  Except maybe by the Church of England.  The fact that states will recognize religious officiants does not constitute a license in the sense you describe.  Or have I missed something?

Comment: A pastor can refuse to marry a couple on religious grounds.  For example, the couple may not be adherents of the pastor's religion, or they may be in violation of some religious principle such as a prohibition against marriage after divorce.  Similarly, if it is against the principles of a religion for people of the same sex to marry, then such couples could be refused.

Comment: Every doctor is licensed by the state. Is every doctor a government employee?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection between priests and marriage is via laws regulating the solemnization of marriage. Washington's RCW [26.04.050](http://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=26.04.050) is typical:

> ...Justices of the supreme court, judges of the court of appeals,
>   judges of the superior courts, supreme court commissioners, court of
>   appeals commissioners, superior court commissioners, any regularly
>   licensed or ordained minister or any priest, imam, rabbi, or similar
>   official of any religious organization, and judges of courts of
>   limited jurisdiction as defined in RCW 3.02.010

Not ship captains, notice. Solemnization is not required. RCW 26.04.010(4) says

> No regularly licensed or ordained minister or any priest, imam, rabbi,
>   or similar official of any religious organization is required to
>   solemnize or recognize any marriage. A regularly licensed or ordained
>   minister or priest, imam, rabbi, or similar official of any religious
>   organization shall be immune from any civil claim or cause of action
>   based on a refusal to solemnize or recognize any marriage under this
>   section.

There is no similar waiver for non-religious officiants. The First Amendment is theoretically what has limited governments ability to require priests to violate their religious beliefs; but I would not be surprised if that changes in the near future. In which case, permissive laws like the Washington law could be trumped by federal anti-discrimination law.

Comment: Does RCW only apply to Washington or all of the US?

Comment: @EdwardSeverinsen: RCW only applies to Washington, but it is typical of what you would find in any state's legal code.  E.g., [here is the PA code](http://www.legis.state.pa.us/WU01/LI/LI/CT/HTM/23/00.015.003.000..HTM).

Comment: "I would not be surprised if that changes in the near future": Would Catholic priests also be required to marry couples who are divorced in the eyes of the state, but who have no annulment from the church?  Would they be required to marry non-Catholic couples?  I would be very surprised if that changed in the future.

Comment: Well, being divorced is not presently a federally protected class. We can maintain our respective degrees of surprise or lack thereof, and see what happens in the near future. Politics is hard to predict.

Comment: @user6726 but religion *is* federally protected, and I cannot imagine that clergy would ever be forced to marry people who fail to comply with the requirements of the clergy's religion.

Comment: @phoog, I believe you are misinterpreting the First Amendment. It does not say that "If you can cite a religious objection, you are not subject to the law". Using religion as opposed to political ideology as a basis for ignoring law would violate the First Amendment, in establishing religion as a privileged exception to the law. I understand the "cannot imagine" reaction, I just can imagine things going that way.

Comment: @user6726 The first amendment protects the religious organization (e.g., a particular church) and its clergy from being forced to marry people who do not comply with that religion's requirements.  There is no law requiring clergy to marry anyone, they are only authorized to do so.  They are not officers of the state (for which see also the first amendment).  The fact that the couple may be gay (federally protected) or adherents of another religion (also federally protected) is not particularly important.

Comment: @phoog The first amendment does not protect religious organizations from having to comply with laws of general applicability such as anti-discrimination laws. See, for example, Employment Division v. Smith. (The rest of what you said is correct. It's just not the First Amendment that's doing the work here.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it appears to me that the case isn't sufficiently similar. Churches (e.g.) are not public accommodations prohibited from discriminating on the basis of religion, and telling a priest (e.g) whom he must marry is certainly an impediment to the free exercise of religion.

Comment: @phoog All true, but completely irrelevant under current First Amendment law. Anti-discrimination laws are laws of general applicability, and it is very well established in the United States that the First Amendment provides no religious exemption from complying with laws of general applicability.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  Religion is a protected class under a law of general applicability, but no one is going to prosecute a rabbi for refusing to marry a Jew and a Gentile, or a priest for marrying a couple who tell him that of course they will get a divorce and remarry if they want to.

Comment: @Mary Under current First Amendment law, so long as the law is generally applicable, wasn't motivated by religious animus, and advances a substantial public interest, there is no First Amendment free exercise right to violate the law. That doesn't mean that other laws (such as RFRA) don't create such a right. See, for example, Prince v. Massachusetts.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Are you claiming the rabbi and priest *would* be prosecuted?  Because both are discriminating based on religion, which is a protected class

Comment: @Mary No, just that their discrimination is not protected by the First Amendment if the law advances a substantial public interest, as non-discrimination laws do. The right to free exercise of your religion does not give you an exemption from laws of general applicability passed to advance substantial public interests. Otherwise, you could avoiding paying taxes and if you sincerely believed it was against your religion to pay taxes. Again, see Prince v. Massachusetts.

Comment: You contradict yourself.